Java Spring security configuration shared for several servlets
I wrote an application using Java, Spring, Maven and Tomcat. This application is composed with 3 servlets :
a – a first servlet is a mcv server
b – a second servlet is a spring webflow server
c – a third servlet is a rest server
It works well. My java composant are organised under the file java.com.shared57 and are distributed under three folders : iprcrudhp for the rest servlet, mcv for the mcv server, sswfe for the spring webflow server.
This is my web.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
   
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
        
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
        <!-- SECURITY FILTER -->
    
    
    <!-- SERVLET 1 API REST -->
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringRestHib</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/SpringRestHib-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringRestHib</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/re/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!-- SERVLET 2 SPRING WEBFLOW   --> 
  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SecureSpringWebFlow50</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-config.xml, /WEB-INF/config/spring-webapp-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SecureSpringWebFlow50</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/we/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <!-- SERVLET 3 JSP SERVER -->
  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SecureServletServer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/my-jsp-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SecureServletServer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/do/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        
</web-app>


Now, I want to secure this application. I had a new folder named secure. In this folder, I had :
a. a class SecurityConfigPart1 for the first servlet :
package com.shared56.secure;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigPart1 {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    @Bean("springSecurityFilterChain")
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("TEST DE SECURITE");
        
        http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/anonymous*")
        .anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login*")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
        
    return http.build();
            
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }
  
}


b. a class SecurityConfigPart2 for the second servlet :
package com.shared56.secure;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigPart2 {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("TEST DE SECURITE");
        
        http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/anonymous*")
        .anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login*")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
        
    return http.build();
            
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }
    
}


c. a class SecurityConfigPart3 for the third servlet :
package com.shared56.secure;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@Order(3)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigPart3 {

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        
        UserDetails user1 = User.withUsername("user1")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withUsername("user2")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user2Pass"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("adminPass"))
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2, admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("TEST DE SECURITE");
        
        http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/anonymous*")
        .anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login*")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.html")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
        
    return http.build();
            
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    }
    
}


I updated the web.xml file :
I add a listener :
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

and a security filter chain :
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
    
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


The project shares the same authentification for the three servlets.
The project doesn't start. I had the error :
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available


May somebody help me ?
Thanks by advance.
Bye
How can I resolve this problem ?

For starters stop using multiple security configuration those aren't needed. You only need 1 and it should be part of your root configuration (the one from the applicationContext). I would however take a step back and re-consider using 3 servlets, why is that needed in the first place? I could see 2 (splitting the MVC and WebFlow part) all the others could be in 1. That being said you rbean is named filterChain not springSecurityFilterChain. Looks like you are combining some old documentatioms and manuals. Any reason not to use Spring Boot for this, it makes it a lot easier.

In my program, the method SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) in class SecurityConfigPart1 is preceded my the annotation @Bean("springSecurityFilterChain").
I tried to declare three filters springSecurityFilterChain1, springSecurityFilterChain2 and springSecurityFilterChain3 in my web.xml,
I renamed in each class SecurityConfigPart1, SecurityConfigPart2, SecurityConfigPart1 the method filterChain to springSecurityFilterChain1, springSecurityFilterChain2 and springSecurityFilterChain3 and add the annotation

With my modifications, the problem is persistent. I have an error No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChainx' available for each filter.

Again youi don't need 3 filters nor filterchains. You are making things overly complex and complicated.

Maybe I made the thing bad. How can I implement security in my spring project step by step ?
